# IllegalStateException: Range start point not set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using Paging library form Jetpack for loading data. In order to allow users to select multiple items in RecyclerView, I have used the RecyclerView Selection library.

Now, the problem is that when the user selects an item and drags down, the app gets crashed after few items are selected. I am getting the below exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Range start point not set.
```

I don't know what I am missing here. Also, I want to disable drag and select in the `SelectionTracker` but can't find a solution for that. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**

I am attaching the necessary code used for the multi-selection below.

**Adapter**

```
 fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
    object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
        override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
        override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
    }
```

**ItemDetailsLookup**

```
class HomeItemDetailsLookup(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView) : ItemDetailsLookup<Long>() {

override fun getItemDetails(event: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<Long>? {
    val view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)
    if (view != null) {
        return (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as HomeViewHolder).getItemDetails()
    }
    return null
 }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
 selectionTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
        "mySelection",
        rvHome,
        StableIdKeyProvider(rvHome),
        HomeItemDetailsLookup(rvHome),
        StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
    ).build()

    homeAdapter.tracker = selectionTracker
```

Comment: Why not show the code which is actually causing the problem?

Comment: @ZubairYounas I have added the code used for multi-selection. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

While combining paging library and selection library there exists this bug.

No solutions have been found so far.

It happens when paging library calls `notifyItemRangeInserted` on adapter which cause `DefaultSelectionTracker.endRange` method trigger that set `DefaultSelectionTracker.mRange` to null.

> Better try updating your libraries to latest alpha and try again

Comment: Tried updating the libraries to the latest alpha but still facing the same problem :(

Comment: @MehulKanzariya then they haven't fixed the issue yet sadly :)